# How to prevent duplicate logging to tomcat console in catalina.out?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, slf4j

I'm deploying a `war` application to a `tomcat` webserver.
Problem: my logging does both to the application logs, and also to the catalina console logs (which are `catalina.out`).

How can I prevent the duplicate logging into that catalina file?

`log4j2-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APP" fileName="/logs/application.logs" filePattern="/logs/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>

            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="APP" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I also already removed the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` from `/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties`:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

Result: the logging still goes to `catalina.out`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from the `<Loggers>` element.

```
 <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
```

Explanation: the `Catalina.out` file captures everything written to Tomcat's standard output and standard error streams.  Your `CONSOLE` appender is set up to log to standard output.

It appears that the `log4j2-spring.xml` configs are taking precedence over `logging.properties`.  Someone would need to take a look at your setup to understand why.

(My guess is that Spring or something is is giving Tomcat's JVM a `-D` option to set a system property giving the location of the logging config.  The mechanisms that log4j2 uses to locate the configs are described in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

---

> There is then still a problem for me: in my local dev environment, I'd still like to get any logs to console, for not having to step into the decent logfiles. I'd only want to disable the console logging on the remote/test/production servers.

Depending on where the `log4j2-spring.xml` file is (in a WAR file?) you could build two variants of the WAR file with different config files.

Alternatively, it should be possible to put an alternative `log4j2-spring.xml` file into Tomcat's `common` directory so that it overrides the version in the WAR file.

Comment: So is `/logging.properties` ignored completely if I set up my `log4j` xml configuration inside the application?

Comment: While this works, there is then still a problem for me: in my local dev environment, I'd still like to get **any** logs to console, for not having to step into the decent logfiles. I'd only want to disable the console logging on the remote/test/production servers.